# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when calling Dialog.show()

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm seeing this on a Samsung Galaxy S II (GT-I9100G) & Samsung NTT DOCOMO Galaxy S II LTE (SC-03D).

I'm building against level 14, targeting level 10 (min level 3).

I assume it's something to do with themes but have no idea where to start. I'm pretty sure it's not happening on all Galaxy SIIs otherwise I would be getting a lot more reports.

Or maybe the activity has been destroyed by the time this code is called - would that cause it?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
builder.setTitle("my title");
builder.setMessage("my message which has about 7 lines and each line is short");
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);
builder.show();
```

log cat:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:248)
 at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:173)
 at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:161)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java:-2)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:215)
 at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:215)
 at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:251)
 at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
 at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:225)
 at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:823)
```

Comment: what more do you want to see?  All the code is there, called from Activity.onCreate()

Comment: does it run fine on emulator or other devices ?

Comment: only released update yesterday, but from 5,000 users (who have updated) I have now two instances. The other is Samsung NTT DOCOMO Galaxy S II LTE (SC-03D). Neither appear to be using custom firmware.  Runs fine on all my devices/emulators, though I don't have either of those devices.

Comment: I wonder, since this particular dialog is non-critical (in my case), is it safe to catch the exception and just continue. I know in some cases, this approach does not work (when dealing with UI-based exceptions), but maybe it would work here?

Comment: yup, give a try and see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

The code that causes the exception should be that:

*TypedArray.getInt (TypedArray.java:248)*

```
/**
 * Retrieve the integer value for the attribute at <var>index</var>.
 * 
 * @param index Index of attribute to retrieve.
 * @param defValue Value to return if the attribute is not defined.
 * 
 * @return Attribute int value, or defValue if not defined.
 */
public int getInt(int index, int defValue) {
    index *= AssetManager.STYLE_NUM_ENTRIES;
    final int[] data = mData;
    final int type = data[index+AssetManager.STYLE_TYPE];
    if (type == TypedValue.TYPE_NULL) {
        return defValue;
    } else if (type >= TypedValue.TYPE_FIRST_INT
        && type <= TypedValue.TYPE_LAST_INT) {
        // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 248
        return data[index+AssetManager.STYLE_DATA];
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 248
    }

    TypedValue v = mValue;
    if (getValueAt(index, v)) {
        Log.w(Resources.TAG, "Converting to int: " + v);
        return XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(
            v.coerceToString(), defValue);
    }
    Log.w(Resources.TAG, "getInt of bad type: 0x"
          + Integer.toHexString(type));
    return defValue;
}
```

The strange thing is that there is no `getInt()` in `ScrollView.java` (why is there even a ScrollView in that Dialog?). Also the exception looks unusual. You would usually get `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=12345` and not `null`

No real clue what's wrong. But it might in fact be caused by some custom Layout stuff since `getInt` would be usually used like so to query the View attributes

```
case R.styleable.View_scrollbars:
    final int scrollbars = a.getInt(attr, SCROLLBARS_NONE);
    if (scrollbars != SCROLLBARS_NONE) {
        viewFlagValues |= scrollbars;
```

I'd say it's a custom firmware or some software modifications done by Samsung that is causing this.

Comment: The dialog message text is actually about 7 lines long (have now edited the original question) so this would explain why there is a ScrollView.  Also, ScrollView extends FrameLayout and I see the FrameLayout constructor calls TypedArray.getInt() so that could be related...

Comment: The ScrollView is always there [alert_dialog.xml](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.6_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml/?v=source) it just does not scroll when you provide short text.

Answer (score 1):

At constructor time the framework uses a TypedArray to retrive xml data from the xml layout used to inflate the view. Standard android doesn't retrieve an int during constructor time of a ScrollView so it looks like samsung modified that part of the framework. (it should be in a try/cacth/finally block anyway so they didn't do a good job there). The ScrollView you see is the one that is present in the default dialog implementation int those devices (generally all the content of the dialog should be inside of a scrollview in case it doesn't fit the screen, specially in landscape mode).
You can try to inflate your own view and set it with setView of the dialogbuilder.

```
View content = View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_view_content,null);
            TextView message = (TextView)content.findViewById(R.id.my_message);
            message.setText("my message which has about 7 lines and each line is short");
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("my title")
            .setView(content)
            .show();
```

Comment: Thanks, but looking at the source: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/FrameLayout.java it appears that ScrollView constructor calls the FrameLayout constructor which does indeed call the TypedArray.getInt() method - I mentioned this in another comment. And that doesn't use a try-catch-finally either.

Comment: I would prefer to find out exactly what is causing this problem rather than use such a workaround because the core reason could manifest in all sorts of other places.

Comment: Yes, ScrollView extends FrameLayout but if it was the getInt in FrameLayout to cause the exception than it would show in the StackTrace; instead from what you posted the buck stops at ScrollView. It's a pretty weird thing, because it looks like for those devices ScrollView is broken which I can hardly believe. Do you see many occurences of the error?

Comment: Not many occurrences at all.  I suspect that Samsung have modified the ScrollView constructor so that it does the FrameLayout constructor work itself.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when you are iterating or trying to access some index in array/list which is not within the array/list size/lenght.

In your case maybe any other code that deals with arrays. If any code that deals with arrays (check the line where the exception is thrown) exists, please post it.

Another thing, change the `setPositiveButton()` second argument to `new DialogInterface.onClickListener(){}` otherwise it will not be usable :)

Comment: its a standard/common practice to set `null` as a listener for a button to dismiss the dialog window

Comment: I just suggested in case he needs that button for other purposes besides dismissing the dialog.